# How to route exact string in reactJS

Tags: reactjs

Am trying to configure two routes in my application ... one for product page and the other for search results, I tried to do as follow

```
 <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Template>
              <Route exact path="/search" component={SearchResult} />
              <Route path="/:id" component={PropertyTemplate} />
            </Template>
          </Switch>
        </Router>
```

**Template**

```
class Template extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          property: null
        }

      }

      render() {

        return (
          <div>
            {/* HEADER */}
            <Header></Header>
            {/* HEADER */}
            {/* LEFT SIDE */}
            <LeftSide></LeftSide>
            {/* LEFT SIDE */}
            <div id="wrapper">
              {this.props.children}
            </div>

          </div >
        )

      }
    }


    export default Template;
```

but it's not working, both components of `/search` and `/:id` are executed

**note** : id is alphanumeric

Comment: By "/search is matched also in /:id" what do you mean? Are both components rendered?

Comment: when I call `/search` ... I guess yes, as I can that, the "componentDidMount" is executed in both components

Comment: What is the `Template` component?

Comment: What is the exact path that you're testing with? Is your path literally `/search` in your browser?

Comment: @cubrr, yes, I do some logic then I redirect to `/search`

Comment: You might want to move your Switch component (or have another one) wrapping your two innermost Routes

Comment: @Chris, adding anohter switch did it ...

Comment: Great! I'll add that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to move your Switch component (or have another one) wrapping your two innermost Routes.

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Template>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/search" component={SearchResult} />
          <Route path="/:id" component={PropertyTemplate} />
        </Switch>
      </Template>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
```